# Why is my code for partitioning a linked list returning a list with a cycle?

Tags: java, linked-list, partition

I am solving LeetCode problem [86. Partition List](https://leetcode.com/problems/partition-list/description/):

> Given the head of a linked list and a value `x`, partition it such that all nodes **less than** `x` come before nodes **greater than or equal** to `x`.
>
> You should **preserve** the original relative order of the nodes in each of the two partitions.
>
> #### Example 1:
>
> **Input:** `head = [1,4,3,2,5,2], x = 3`
> **Output:** `[1,2,2,4,3,5]`
>
> #### Example 2:
>
> **Input:** `head = [2,1], x = 2`
> **Output:** `[1,2]`
>
> #### Constraints:
>
> - The number of nodes in the list is in the range `[0, 200]`.
> - `-100 <= Node.val <= 100`
> - `-200 <= x <= 200`

My code:

```
    public static ListNode partition(ListNode head, int x) {
        ListNode lesser = new ListNode(-101);
        ListNode less = lesser;
        ListNode greater = new ListNode(-101);
        ListNode great = greater;
        ListNode temp= head;
        while(temp!=null){
            if(temp.val<x){
                less.next=temp;
                less=less.next;
            }
            else{
                great.next=temp;
                great=great.next;
            }
            temp=temp.next;
        }


        less.next = great.next;
        return lesser.next;
    }
```

I get this error back from the tests:

> Error - Found cycle in the ListNode

Can anybody explain why this error occurs?

Comment: hard without the input data.... you can try to debug it, eventually using this [Java Visualizer](https://cscircles.cemc.uwaterloo.ca/java_visualize)

Comment: I suspect when *transferring* a node to the lesser or greater list, its `next` is not being deleted and `less.next = great.next` will eventually create a loop

Answer (score 1):

The problem is at the end of your code:

After the loop, `great` points to the node with the last value that was found greater (or equal) than the pivot. It should thus become the **tail** of your final list. But it might well be that in the original list it was followed by a node with a small value, and this link has not been changed.

For instance, with the input example `2→1` and =2, we get this situation before the loop starts:

```
lesser less
   ↓     ↓
┌───────────┐
│ val: -101 │
│ next: null│
└───────────┘                    
                                 
greater great      head  temp
   ↓      ↓         ↓     ↓
┌───────────┐     ┌───────────┐     ┌───────────┐
│ val: -101 │     │ val: 2    │     │ val: 1    │
│ next: null│     │ next: ─────────►│ next: null│
└───────────┘     └───────────┘     └───────────┘
```

After the first iteration:

```
lesser less
   ↓     ↓
┌───────────┐
│ val: -101 │
│ next: null│
└───────────┘                    
                                 
greater            head great        temp
   ↓                 ↓    ↓            ↓
┌───────────┐     ┌───────────┐     ┌───────────┐
│ val: -101 │     │ val: 2    │     │ val: 1    │
│ next: ─────────►│ next: ─────────►│ next: null│
└───────────┘     └───────────┘     └───────────┘
```

After the second iteration:

```
lesser
   ↓
┌───────────┐
│ val: -101 │
│ next: ────────────────────────┐
└───────────┘                   │ 
                                │ 
greater            head great   │     less       temp==null
   ↓                 ↓    ↓     │       ↓
┌───────────┐     ┌───────────┐ │   ┌───────────┐
│ val: -101 │     │ val: 2    │ └──►│ val: 1    │
│ next: ─────────►│ next: ─────────►│ next: null│
└───────────┘     └───────────┘     └───────────┘
```

And now the faulty statement `less.next = great.next` will introduce the loop -- the node with value 1 gets a self reference!

First, realise that `less` is the last node of the first partition, and `great` the last node of the second partition. That means that `great.next` should be set to `null` -- it really must be the last node in the final list.

Secondly, it is true that `less.next` should be updated, but it should be set to the *first* node of the second partition, which is `greater.next` (not `great.next`).

Correction:

```
        great.next = null; // added
        less.next = greater.next; // corrected
```

After these two statements the example will resolve to:

```
lesser
   ↓
┌───────────┐
│ val: -101 │
│ next: ────────────────────────┐
└───────────┘                   │ 
                                │ 
greater            head great   │     less       temp==null
   ↓                 ↓    ↓     │       ↓
┌───────────┐     ┌───────────┐ │   ┌───────────┐
│ val: -101 │     │ val: 2    │ └──►│ val: 1    │
│ next: ─────────►│ next:null │     │ next: ─┐  │
└───────────┘  ┌─►└───────────┘     └────────│──┘
               └─────────────────────────────┘
```

And when we return `lesser.next` (correct), the local variables run out of scope, and the above simplifies to:

```
                                     (returned)     
                                        ↓
                  ┌───────────┐     ┌───────────┐
                  │ val: 2    │     │ val: 1    │
               ┌─►│ next:null │     │ next: ─┐  │
               │  └───────────┘     └────────│──┘
               └─────────────────────────────┘
```

Answer (score 0):

- `lesser` is the first part, starting with a dummy node.
- `greater` is the second part, starting with a dummy node.
- `less` is the tail of the first part.
- `great` is the tail of the second part.

*Better names would have helped.*

At the end: remove the dummies and tie the  end of the tails.

```
great.next = null; // When a smaller followed
less.next = greater.next;
lesser = lesser.next;
return lesser;
```

As `less` could have been `lesser` and `great` be `greater` the order of rewiring the links is important.

You might have opted for

```
ListNode left = null;
ListNode leftTail = null;
ListNode right = null;
ListNode rightTail = null;

while (head != null) {
    if (head.val < x) {
        if (left == null) {
            left = head;
        } else {
            leftTail.next = head;
        }
        leftTail = head;
    } else {
        if (right == null) {
            right = head;
        } else {
            rightTail.next = head;
        }
        rightTail = head;
    }
    head = head.next;
}
if (rightTail != null) {
    rightTail.next = null;
}
if (leftTail != null) {
    leftTail.next = right;
} else {
    left = right;
}
return left;
```

The above one should have seen (at least once), where the LHS variable stems from a condition, the RHS being the same value.
In a language like C one would use this style, with *aliases*.

Answer (score 0):

I have modified your code based on your design premise.
The exception is you have not deal the node as a simple node ,you think you just put a node after less and great.But actually you put the linked list after the less and great so that the cycle appeared.
The follow is my code .

```
public static ListNode partition(ListNode head, int x) {
        ListNode lesser = new ListNode(-101);
        ListNode less = lesser;
        ListNode greater = new ListNode(-101);
        ListNode great = greater;
        while(head!=null){
            ListNode temp= head;
            head = head.next;
            //this is important ,to cut the list to a single node
            temp.next = null;
            if(temp.val<x){
                less.next=temp;
                less=less.next;
            }
            else{
                great.next=temp;
                great=great.next;
            }
        }


        less.next = greater.next;
        return lesser.next;
    }
```